# I need a bower alternative

Tags: package-managers, web-frontend

I am working on a project with dotnet core, in Linux and it is using MVC.

I am reading a book for learning how to put things together. The book advises installing Bower. But the last time I researched bower I believe they were advising towards using something else for new projects.

I would like to know what alternative I can use for front end management. I need to be able to use Bootstrap, Jquery, Popper and Datatables on my page. And of course, I should be able to use it in Linux.

Comment: [NPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) is the defacto these days (Yarn is an alternative NPM client, but does mostly the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help francium. NPM is working just fine.It is in the official Ubuntu repository. You have to install popper the following way though: `npm install popper.js --save` 
If you don't specify the .js extension it will give you a warning saying that bootstrap requires a popper installation but it was not installed. You also have to install git on your machine to make it work. I did not do it the first time I ran it and it gave me an error asking me if it was installed. Thanks for the suggestion, It was relatively easy to do get things working.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn is now the alternative to Bower, but to install Yarn you need to use NPM

Comment: So NPM = IE? :D